# Having trouble with vscode code completion for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble with JavaScript code completion in VS Code. For example, here I am trying to use `process.std.write()` but the code completion gives me other suggestions.
[image]

I can not avoid this, even when I jsut try to write process with out the code completion, it will just change it to the first suggestion that came up. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a standard node module, you have to import/require it first.

and the function is called `process.stdout.write`

```js
const process = require('process');

process.stdout.write();
```

Comment: Great, concise, and works perfectly.